# Rollback Service installation in unattended mode with install4j

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to create an Install4j updater in unattended mode using Stand Alone Update Downloader and invoke it using the api. (this is working)

The application is a Windows Service and it opens http ports.

I would like to be able to rollback to the previous installed service if the new installed version isn't working. There should be no user interaction to do it.

What I was planning to do is:

- Install the service
- Start the service
- Call Wait for Http Server Action that calls an Url of the service to check if my new updated service is working as intended.
- If it doesn't returns a 2xx it will initiate the rollback process

But what I'm seeing is that the rollback process starts but it stops and uninstalls the new service but the previous service is never reinstalled.

What I would want it to do when rollbacking is:

- Stop the new service
- Uninstall it
- Rollback any other files added by the new version
- Reinstall the previous service
- Start the previous service

Is there any way to achieve it ?

Edit:
I have those actions in the installer:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a "Execute previous uninstaller" action in your project? A rollback cannot undo the uninstallation perfomed by that action.

Comment: No we don't have "Execute previous uninstaller" action in our project

Comment: I added a screenshot of the installer for more info
Since the Install a service and start a service are after Wait for http server, it rollbacks those steps and it removes the previous service

Comment: We managed to make it works this way:
1) Adding a stop a service action before install files: so on the rollback it rollback the stop and restart the service.
2) Adding a condition expression on the "install a service" like that: !context.isUpdateInstallation() so it isn't run on updates, this way the rollback doesn't uninstall the service. I don't know if there's a better way ?

Comment: Sounds good, I've created an issue to improve the default behavior for the next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this version of Install4j (10.0.4) the rollback mechanism doesn't handle this scenario. As specified by the comment of Ingo Kegel this will be improved in further version.

What is working with this version is that:
[image]

Add the condition on Install service to not to run it when updating like this:  `!context.isUpdateInstallation()`. There will no rollback of the service when updating.

To keep the service started, we added a Stop a Service at the beginning. This way if there's a rollback, the Stop a Service will be rollbacked, so it will restart the service.